# IOS builds fine but gives error when run on device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

Hello I have a problem when I compile and build a swift project. 
it compiles fine but when it was supposed to run on my test Device the device screen blinks with a white startup screen and shortly after Xcode reports this:

> process launch failed: Unspecified

and after that first run any run will report

> process launch failed: Disabled

instead.

I've tried so many things.
including:
cleaning the derived files making a clean before build.
clean the MacBook and the phone after a reboot try to compile again.
I've tried to change signing identities and provisioning profile. 
only resulted in a lot of mess with signing identities that I would be fearful for entering again.

I do not know what to do please help ?

**EDIT**

I have also tried to create a new project and just copy the content of the files in to it no changes to the project files except those Really needed that I know it worked with before. same results.

I had som signing problems and have changed the Signing Identity a few times as well as the provisioning profile. I'm not sure if this could cause problems but I don't get an error from the signing anymore.

**EDIT2**

I have now made a factory reset of the phone just to eliminate that as the cause. As expected the problem still persist. 
I'm considering to make a backup of my Mac from a earlier point to make sure that it is not the cause either simply making sure that the project files or something in the compilation are the problem. ?

I'm striking my head against a wall here any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: After the run fails, do you see your app installed on your device? After the run fails and Xcode has stopped, try opening the app on your device by tapping its icon on the device. What happens?

Comment: @MikeTaverne the app opens up to a white screen and closes down Immediately the app is installed and have been running before but just aren't anymore :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've finally solved my problem. I still do not know what caused it. But it must have been a setting in the project or a framework that was not removed entirely.

My solution was to create a new branch of a earlier working branch, and just write in all the files and changes that was between them without touching the project files or import any frameworks. I avoided copy pasting as last time I created an entire new project I copy pasted most of the files and I think something went wrong in that as the result was the same problem.
Hopefully this answer will be elaborated on by someone who knows more than me about this but currently this was the only way I could make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "*Launch due to a background fetch event*" box in the **Edit Scheme menu**

Here are steps for the same

1. In Xcode, click the button that includes your app's name that is to the immediate right of the Stop button
2. Click "Edit Scheme..." in the dropdown menu
3. Make sure "Run" is selected on the left and "Options" is selected at the top
4. The Background Fetch box will be in the middle of the view

   [image]

Comment: I already did this. it was a good guess thou because I've seen many who got theirs solved with this solution. but mine never was checked and I have double checked several times now